# how to add app object in flask's main file

Tags: flask

I want to add app object once in main.py which can be used everywhere, but route does not work in this way. What is the issue here?

main.py

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)


if __name__ == "__main__":
   app.run(debug=True)
```

routes.py

```
from main import app

@app.route("/", methods = ["GET"])
def home():    
        return "hi"
```

However, if declare app = Flask(**name**)   in routes.py and import app in main.py it is working all fine. Working scenario.

main.py

```
from routes import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
   app.run(debug=True)
```

routes.py

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/", methods = ["GET"])
def home():
        return "hi"
```

my objective is to define app in main.py and import it in other files, but getting issues.

Answer (score 0):

`main.py` is not even aware that `routes.py` exists. Import your `routes.py` file after initializing your app.

```py
# main.py

from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

import routes  # needed

if __name__ == "__main__":
   app.run(debug=True)
```

```py
# routes.py

from __main__ import app

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return "hi"
```

Comment: not working. i do not understand how "import routes"  in main will make a difference when route function are not called in main.py

Comment: @myquest5sh sorry I was missing the `from __main__ import app` at top. Edited the answer to include this. However, I highly recommend that you look into blueprints instead of implementing it this way. I simply wanted to let you know this solution exists, but it's not the desirable one imho.